# How do I create the final executable file using `make`?

Tags: linux, makefile, dynamic-linking, gtk2

I am trying to write a makefile for a small project which uses GTK libraries.

```
# Compiler
cc = gcc

#Options for Development
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

all: pss

pss : main.o interface.o
#   $(cc) $(CFLAGS) -o pss main.o interface.o

main.o : main.c interface.h
interface.o : interface.c
```

`pss` is supposed to be the final executable file. However, the makefile does not create the executable `pss`. When I explicitly add the line for creating `pss`, then I am getting a linking error.

```
asheesh:~/Source$ make
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` -o pss main.o interface.o
interface.o: In function `interface':
interface.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `gtk_init'
interface.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'
interface.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
interface.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `gtk_main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pss] Error 1
```

How do I create the final executable file using `make`?

Changed the makefile to handle library dependencies properly. Still not working.

```
#Options for Development
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

#Libraries
LIBS   = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

all: pss

pss : main.o interface.o
    $(cc) $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS) -o pss main.o interface.o

main.o : main.c interface.h
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) -o main.o main.c interface.o


interface.o : interface.c
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o interface.o interface.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what the problem was, but it got solved by manually specifying the compile commands.

```
# Compiler
cc = gcc

#Options for Development
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

#Libraries
LIBS   = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

all: pss

pss : main.o interface.o
    $(cc) -o pss main.o interface.o $(LIBS)
#   $(cc) $(LIBS) -o pss main.o interface.o
#   This line fails to link whereas the line above works.

main.o : main.c interface.h
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c interface.c

interface.o : interface.c
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) -c interface.c
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your compilation phase is not able to find include files.  When I see how you built your `.o` files, there is no `-I` flag to indicate where to find `gtk` include files.

You may want to add suffix rules:

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .o
.c.o:
        gcc -c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` $<
```

Comment: If you look at the `main.o` in your posting, you have not specified the extra flags to include directories in there.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten '-c' option while building .o files (in your first message).
You also don't need to include *.o or *.c files in compile phase:

```
$(cc) $(CFLAGS) -o main.o main.c interface.o // wrong
$(cc) $(CFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.c // right
```

and to your last code:

```
# Compiler
CC = gcc // Fixed: CAPSLOCK here

#Options for Development
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

#Libraries
LIBS   = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

all: pss

pss : main.o interface.o
    $(cc) -o pss main.o interface.o $(LIBS)
#   $(cc) $(LIBS) -o pss main.o interface.o
#   This line fails to link whereas the line above works.

main.o : main.c interface.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

interface.o : interface.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c interface.c
```

Also you can write 5 last lines even simpler:

```
main.o : main.c interface.h

interface.o : interface.c
```

No recipes needed because of the implicit rule for building .o from .c with recipe in a form:

```
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c
```

Comment: What was wrong in the original file? I am not sure what you are trying  to point out.

Comment: @Arks: `-c` to *compile* `.o` files? You should review what you wrote ;)